# How to use PHP Regular Expressions to find and return a portion of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I would like to find and return a sentence that starts with "Find" and ends with "eBay.", but I cannot get it to work. Here's what I have now:

```
if (preg_match("/^Find eBay\.$/", $post->post_content) == 1) {

                    $description = preg_grep("/^Find eBay\.$/", $post->post_content);

                } else {

                    $description = $this->trim_excerpt_without_filters($this->internationalize($post->post_content));

                }
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Edit**

This is the string I'm searching:

```
<p><a href="http://cgi.ebay.com/ebaymotors/?cmd=ViewItem&amp;_trksid=p3984.m1438.l2649&amp;item=110804005978&amp;sspagename=STRK%3AMEWAX%3AIT">here on eBay</a>Find this 1969 Chevrolet Camaro COPO 427 for sale in New York, .</p>
```

Comment: the string you are searching neither starts with Find Nor ends with eBay...

Comment: You're right! (dur) Wordpress is formatting it weird. Strange, but unrelated to this post. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, the .* means any number of any character

```
/^Find.*eBay\.$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it is still returning negative. :( Also, I updated my question with the string. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your example string doesn't start with "Find" nor end with "eBay", so it will not match your example string.

To match your example, you will need to use something like this:

```
/eBay\<\/a\>Find/
```

That will match a string that contains `eBay</a>Find` (though you could use just use a simple search for that instead of a regex).